# How to handle a 204 response in a Backbone.js collection request

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

In my Backbone.js based app I am talking to my API that responds with a 204 status and an empty body, in case a collection is requested which does not contain any data yet. That's in my opinion how a RESTful API should respond in such case.

In my app now I have the problem, that obviously no event is triggered after a 204 response was received. I tried to bind `reset` and `all` like:

```
  FoosCollectionView.prototype.initialize = function() {
    this.collection = new FoosCollection;
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    this.collection.bind('all', this.render, this);
    return this.collection.fetch();
  };
```

but the events never fire. So I tried to give fetch some callbacks:

```
  FoosCollectionView.prototype.initialize = function() {
    this.collection = new FoosCollection();
    return this.collection.fetch({
      success: function(a, b, c) {
        debugger;
      },
      error: function(a, b, c) {
        debugger;
      },
      complete: function(a, b) {
        debugger;
      }
    });
  };
```

Same behaviour. No debug statement is ever reached in case the response is a 204. How can I handle 204 responses then? Will I have to dig down into `sync` and add an extra handling for 204 there or is there something in Backbone that I simply don't know yet?

Thx Felix

Comment: As far as I found out, I could add some login to the collections parse method. But handling the rendering of a 'no-content' view from there seems ugly.

Comment: I found a solution that seems at least a little more elegant. I define parse in my collections. Inside I check whether the given response is empty. If so, I set the collections models to [] which in turn triggers the reset event. The collection view is bound to that event and can afterwards render some "no content here" template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems pretty forward and awkward at the same time:

I simply define the `parse` method in my collections so that it checks, whether the passed response object is empty. That's only the case when a 204 occured. Then inside `parse` I set `this.collection.models = []` which triggers a `reset` event. The collections view is bound to that event, runs a function which can have a look inside `this.collection.models`. In case no models are given, a 'no-content' template can be rendered instead the standard template.

If someone has a better approach, I'd appreciate to here that!

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js wraps such responses into empty collection. I'm using this as workaround.

```
render: function(){
   if (this.collection.length == 0) {
       console.log('empty response');
       // initialize with default values
       this.collection.reset(data);
   }
   // do usual stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has occurred today, and say from conclusion, my code was wrong.
After modifying the code, `success()` callback was called when the server responds with `204 No Content`.

Backbone: 1.2.3
jQuery: 2.1.4

**Wrong code:**

```js
FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/foo',

  model: FooModel,

  fetch: function (options) {

    // do something.

    // Actually, you should call `Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch()`.
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
  }
});
```

So, if you experience this problem, you should check if there is any error in the code.
Anyway, if you want to handle the `204 No Content` response, there is the following method. **(not recommended)**

```js
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new FooCollection();

    var _this = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function (collection, response, options) {
      },
      error: function (collection, response, options) {
      }
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (jqXHR.status === 204) {
        // do something.
        // e.g. _this.collection.reset();
      }
    });
  }
```